# How to generate MD5 hash with a salt in command line?

Tags: command-line, hashing, md5, md5sum

password: rose

salt: jack123

MD5 hash value: bf57b6634a951e3ee7ff2bbfb6206ec0

The above-given output was generated on a website (http://md5.my-addr.com/md5_salted_hash-md5_salt_hash_generator_tool.php) that generates hashes based on input string and salt.
How can I generate the same hash value using the same password "rose" and salt "jack123" on command line using md5?

I am a beginner, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If on a Mac:

```
md5 -s 'jack123rose'
```

This outputs the MD5 hash:

```
MD5 ("jack123rose") = bf57b6634a951e3ee7ff2bbfb6206ec0
```

Answer (score 0):

To produce a salted hash, you merely have to prepend the salt value to the data you want to hash. For your example:

```
password=rose
salt=jack123
echo -n "$salt$password" |md5sum
```